# What is the best way to loop through images as an ajax loading progress indicator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage where folks can search for specific people.  the queries on the back end can take a while (up to 30 seconds . .) so right now i am showing a regular ajax loading image [from the ajaxload](http://www.ajaxload.info/) website but i was thinking it would look a little slicker if i could instead of the a regular circle spinning have randomized images of the different thumbnails of people (maybe a few in a row) looping while the ajax is running.

A few questions:

1. Are there any jquery plugins or other suggestions for doing sometihng like this? would it be better to try to create an animated gif from some pictures?
2. Would be if i was loading images from the server is that going to conflict with the ajax search query in terms of performance, etc..

Comment: try http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery-ui.html

Comment: 1) http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/ 2) No, it will not cause issues. you may like to preload the slides anyway.

Comment: i think images of people is going to be less obvious to users of progress indication than a spinny would. that will make them subconsciously like your app less. you can preload any gif images to prevent any performance hits upon image display.

Comment: I would go with the gif for several reasons. 1 it's very small; 2 won't conflict with the in any way; 3 it's easy to make ... etc

Comment: @rafealcastrocout - how would i create an animated gif from a set of pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know what images you want to show as the loading is happening, you could use maybe a carousel plugin?

[JCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) seems like a good bet

If your images are already on the page before the ajax kicks off, then there will be no performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

There will most likely be a performance hit when you want to use the query results as images. But it might depend if it significant because of the 30 second thing.

Why does what sounds like simple query (looking up people) take so lang anyway? You might want to try and fix that.